# Findbugs in Eclipse ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception when running

Tags: java, findbugs, java-8

I just installed (and re-installed) Findbugs in Eclipse Juno and every time I try to run it in any of my projects I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Finding bugs in <project name>...".
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Googling didn't provide any useful results. Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried (and probably failed) to install Java 8's test version in Eclipse to try out Java 8's lambdas and other features. Maybe it has something to do with Findbugs not running properly?

Comment: I am getting the same problem with Netbeans 7.4 RC2. Using findbugs-maven-plugin:2.5.2. FindBugs throws exceptions like `Unable to get XClass for java/lang/StringBuilder` printing the stack trace of a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` coming from `org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass`, `rg.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept` and `du.umd.cs.findbugs.asm.FBClassReader.accept(FBClassReader.java:44)`. Using java 1.8.0-ea-b109.

Comment: have you tried: eclipse -clean from command line?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

FB official release is not yet (2.0.3) compatible with Java 8 class file format.

However, the perfectly working Eclipse plugin daily build of 3.0.0 version is available from this update site: http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse-daily

We plan to release 3.0.0 RC1 in the next few days (till the end of the Juni 2014).

Comment: What if you want to compile java7 code using jdk8 via ecj(4.3)? I have "source="1.7" target="1.7" and <compilerarg line="-1.7" /> set and am still getting errors :-/

Comment: The case you've describing should work, so report a bug in FB bug tracker :-)

Comment: Sooo - WHEN does this cometh? Eclipse 4.4 is JUST around the corner, and Java 8 is on its second download (u5).